# How to get raw probability values for each class in Tensorflow?

Tags: classification, tensorflow

How could I obtain raw probability values of the tested sample's resemblance to each one of the N classes (my use case is based on the [TensorFlow Mechanics 101](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/tutorials/mnist/tf/index.html) tutorial)?

E.g., instead of running `tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, labels, 1)`, I would like to set up a threshold that returns `True` in case the tested sample resembles the second label with a probability of >= 0.25.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [greater_equal](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops.html#greater_equal) method. For example

```python
threshold = tf.constant(0.25, dtype=tf.float32)
raw_prob = tf.greater_equal(predictions, threshold)
```

`raw_prob`will be a tensor of same size as `predictions` holding `True` or `False`. It is also possible to use different thresholds for different classes. Assuming that number of classes is three:

```python
threshold = tf.constant([0.34, 0.25, 0.95], dtype=tf.float32)
raw_prob = tf.greater_equal(predictions, threshold)
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this approach